# SP2 for windows server 2008 r2 datacenter

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2

I have windows server 2008 r2 datacenter.

I want to install SP2 to solve some issues.

When I download the SP2 it says that this patch does not apply to my windows version

Where is the SP2 for datacenter? it is not in windows update

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no service pack 2 yet for Server 2008 R2.  Service Pack 1 was released in March.  Server 2008 has a service pack 2 however.

Answer (score 2):

Windows Server 2008 has an SP2, which is probably what you downloaded.

The current version of Windows Server 2008 R2 is SP1.

Different patches and service packs apply to these different versions; Windows 2008 is to Windows Vista as Windows 2008 R2 is to Windows 7.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that there IS NO 2008 R2 SP2 at the moment.

What you got is SP2 for 2008 - not 2008 R2. Sp1 was released 15th of March, Sp2 is not out yet.

2008 R2 is newer ;)

Funny - you should REALLY be more carefull when playing with pro equipment. At least check that you download the right service pack.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server_2008_R2#Service_Pack_1 has more infos.